# What tools have been used to build StackOverflow Help Center?

Tags: discussion, help-center

Is SO Help Center built from scratch (ASP.NET) or  is it based on some tool ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you. Already read the answers on your link. This specific information was not mentioned.

Comment: If any more specific tool had been used it would have been mentioned there, I am sure.

Answer (score 3):

Built from scratch using ASP.NET/MVC and SQL Server, like the rest of Stack Overflow.

Also see [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: Thank you. How do you know that ? it's not mentioned anywhere even on your link

Comment: @MonsieurLight he's a developer working for SE meaning he has direct access to the source code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thank you

Comment: ... unlike it's predecessor, the venerable FAQ, which wasn't written, but _carved_, in stone.